# Freezing weight of neural network such that its output takes a particular value at a particular point (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Let's say I have a neural network that looks like this

```
def neural_net(x):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)

    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer
```

Is there a way in tensorflow to fix the weights in such a way that `neural_net(a)` always returns `b` (where `a,b` are real numbers), e.g., `f(1) = 0`?

Comment: Why are you using neural networks for this? Fixed value output seems more appropriate for a function.

Comment: I want to train a neural network with data, but it is important that the neural net gives me exact outputs for some particular values.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, however, the answer depends a bit on the purpose.

The easiest solution is to just scale the output. For example by running the result through a linear regressor. While this gives the desired result it is probably not what you want.

However, probably the better way is to integrate this additional objective in the loss function during training. This way you can trade off between your additional requirement and fitting the weights of your neural network. A generic description how to adapt the loss you can find at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.losses

```
images, labels = LoadData(...)
predictions = MyModelPredictions(images)

weight = MyComplicatedWeightingFunction(labels)
weight = tf.div(weight, tf.size(weight))
loss = tf.contrib.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions, depths, weight)
```

The weight for your special case need to be extremely high.
That way your critiria is not full guarantee but very likely.

In addition you need to rewrite the mini-batching mechanism to inject in each batch your `(x,y) = (1,0)` example

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I thought of doing something similar, but this just seems super expensive to me. Could you think of any more efficient solution?

Comment: @timudk it depends very much what your goal is. Something like you describe is for example done for watermarking https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2018/07/ai-watermarking/. The costs are I guess not relevant in comparison to the overall training costs.

Comment: My goal is to approximate a function, and I want the boundaries to take the exact values of the function that is approximated.